# Filter list matching all ids

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq query:

```
FilteredProducts = AllProducts.Where(p => p.Attributes.Any(a => Filters.Contains(a.ID)));
```

Where `Filters` is a `List<int>`.  The above query returns any products that matches any of the attribute ids in `Filters`.

How can I change this so only products that match all the ids in `Filters` are returned (it can also have other attributes but must have any attribute that has an id in Filters).

I thought about using Intersect instead of Any but then I would have to use a list of attributes (which I don't really want to do)

Comment: You could reverse the logic, and use Filters.All inside the where. Untested, but something like `FilteredProducts = AllProducts.Where(p => Filters.All(fa=> p.Attributes.Any(a=> a.ID == fa)));`

Comment: @Me.Name that's perfect, if you add that as an answer I'll mark it - I tried reversing it when Janiec put up an answer to use all but I couldn't get the inner logic correct

Comment: Ah great, wasn't sure the syntax by hand would hold up, but will post as an answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to reverse the logic and test filters.all inside the products where clause

```
AllProducts.Where(p => Filters.All(fa=> p.Attributes.Any(a=> a.ID == fa)));
```